# Connect SVG line from div to div

Tags: html, css, svg, line

Is there any possible way, to connect two div's with a SVG drawed line, but by using the cordinates of div's dimensions...
I will try to make it more clear:

If the divs have this attributes:

```
#divR {
   background-color: red;
   width: 350px;
   height: 300px;
   /*Im trying to avoid divs positions*/
}

#divB {
   background-color: blue;
   width: 350px;
   height: 400px;
   /*Im trying to avoid divs positions*/
}
```

And here is the default html code of a SVG line:

```
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
```

And my question is, how to give the cordinations of divs size like redbox the edge of width `x1="350"`, and the half of the height `y1="150"`, and the bluebox `x2="0"` and `y2="200"`.

Here is an image Ive done to help understanding this:

[image]

I hope I was clear enough... :S

Comment: No, that is not possible without the use of JavaScript to read the element positions and calculate the right coordinates to set in the SVG.

Comment: Ou okay, :S I expected this... Cuz when I use percentage of positions, I never get the cordinates of the div's right... They move so the line draws out :D :S Anyway thanks...